# Get command result from SSH/Telnet via another SSH jump server in Python

Tags: python, ssh, telnet, paramiko, portforwarding

I am writing a Python code to SSH or Telnet remote hosts, execute some commands and get the result output. Here we have a jump server, so the code must be "connected" with this server and from it, Telnet or SSH the remote hosts.

All my approaches work fine within the jump server, for example I can get the output of commands inside it. The problem is when I try to remote connect to hosts from it.

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()

client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('IP', 22, username="user", password="pass")
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("command")
for line in stdout:
     print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))
client.close()
```

Using the library jumpssh get same results, and I am not will able to Telnet hosts. I tried the follow approach, but get the error

> Administratively prohibited.

```
from jumpssh import SSHSession

gateway_session = SSHSession('jumpserver','user', password='pass').open()
remote_session = gateway_session.get_remote_session('IP',password='pass')
print(gateway_session.get_cmd_output('command'))
```

In the last company i worked we had a license from an SSH client that supports Python scripts, and worked fine in a more "textual" treatment.

There is any way of accomplish same task natively in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SSHSession` is trying to open `direct-tcpip` port forwarding channel over the `gateway_session`.

*"administratively prohibited"* is OpenSSH `sshd` server message indicating that `direct-tcpip` port forwarding is disabled.

To enable port forwarding, set [`AllowTcpForwarding`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AllowTcpForwarding) and [`DisableForwarding`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#DisableForwarding) directives in `sshd_config` appropriately.

---

If you cannot enable the port forwarding on the server, you cannot use jumpssh library.

If you have a shell access to the server, you can use [`ProxyCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand)-like approach instead.
See [Paramiko: nest ssh session to another machine while preserving paramiko functionality (ProxyCommand)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42208655/850848).

Comment: Now i found what i was doing wrong, the channel was closing after command. i followed this  thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943385/how-to-interact-with-paramikos-interactive-shell-session and is working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, you need this: [Pass input/variables to command/script over SSH using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50749745/850848).